# Python - Split content of text file when specific string is found

Tags: python, text-files, discord.py

I am currently using the following code below to split the contents of a text file that is read every 2000 characters to ensure that discord.py message limit is not exceeded.

This is working fine, but the slight issue is sometimes a word in a message will be split across two messages, as the code just splits the message as soon as it reaches 2000 characters.

I was thinking that a better solution would be to look for a specific string that is common between each block of content in the text file and split when this string is found.

The code I am currently using is below

```
with open(info["textfile"], 'r') as file:
                    msg = file.read(2000).strip()
                    while len(msg) > 0:
                        await message.author.send(msg)
                        msg = file.read(2000).strip()
```

I was thinking that I would need to use .contains to search for the string to then split the content of the text files to be sent as a message but I cannot work out how I would go about implementing this.

An example of the text file content is below:

```
__**Competition**__: Professional Boxing - 10 Rounds Lightweight Bout 
__**Competitors:**__: Katie Taylor v Delfine Persoon 
__**Match Date:**__: Saturday, 22nd  August 
__**Match Time:**__: ST: 21:00 
__**Channels**__: DAZN USA   
   Sky Sports Box Office HD 
-----
__**Competition**__: Professional Boxing - 12 Rounds Heavyweight Bout 
__**Competitors:**__: Dillian Whyte v Alexander Povetkin 
__**Match Date:**__: Saturday, 22nd  August 
__**Match Time:**__: ST: 22:00 
__**Channels**__: DAZN USA   
   Sky Sports Box Office HD 
-----
```

I was thinking it would be best to search for "-----" and spliting the content of the text file at this point to then send each group of match data as a separate message?

Thank you to anyone who can provide assistance or a solution to this isue.

Comment: You can use [`string.split('-----')`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), which splits the string into a list of strings, and then send each item in the list as a new message.

Comment: The answer is: yes. Do it. Split it at ---- and send each group as a separate message. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks both. If anyone wants to transfer their advice into an answer i can accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the assistance from dantechguy and Thomas Weller the solution to the problem I had is below:

```
with open(info["textfile"], 'r') as file: # using with to open file means we don't have to close it after finishing
                    msg = file.read().strip().split ("--------------------") # reads content of textfile and split when "-------------------" is found and creates list of strings.
                    for item in msg:  # for loop to call each item
                        print (item) # print to double check output 
                        await message.author.send(item) # send each item as a new message in discord.
```

As explained in their comments, all that needed to be done was split on the "---------------------" to split the string into a list of strings then send each item as a message.